# Multiplying elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml

```
<DATASET>
<DS>
    <Name>AB</Name>
    <Price>17000</Price>
    <Dates>10/12/2018</Dates>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Total>0</Total>
    <Notes></Notes>
</DS>
<DS>    
    <Name>CD</Name>
    <Price>20000</Price>
    <Dates>10/12/2018</Dates>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Total>0</Total>
    <Notes></Notes>
</DS>
</DATASET>
```

I want to calculate Total = Quantity*Price. How can I do that in XML and C#

Currently I have listed the xml file to datagridview. So how can I calculate the total and then write it back to xml file? I tried doc.save(path) but it not working.

```
public void readxml()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = @"D:\Project_VS13\FORM\WindowsFormsBTL_1\DATA_BTL.xml";
        doc.Load(path);
        DataSet tab = new DataSet();
        tab.ReadXml(path);
        DataTable dtb = tab.Tables["DS"];  
        DataTable dt_view = new DataTable();
        //dt_view = dtb.Clone();
        XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(path);
        //new column
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Item Name");
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Price (USD)");
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Order Date");
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Ordered Quantity");
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Totals");
        dt_view.Columns.Add("Notes");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtb.Rows)
        {
                dt_view.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt_view;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Presumably you know how to perform multiplication - so is this really about extracting the values from the elements and then setting values in elements afterwards? If so, I'd recommend reading a LINQ to XML tutorial, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml. You'll learn a lot more from that than if someone just gives you a very specific answer to this problem. After reading that tutorial, if you try and then still have issues, please post what you've tried and we can help you fix it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what output do you need?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I'm sorry for my late response. I'm working right now so I couldn't try any. I'll try it once I get home.

Comment: Do I have to connect LinQ dtb through SQL server? If so, I can't use it because all I can use is XML not SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read your xml file by using `XDocument`. Then by using linq you can iterate over each child of your `DATASET` node and inside `select` clause of linq you can calculate `Total = Quantity x Price` like

```
class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

        var result = from d in doc.Descendants("DATASET").Elements("DS")
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = d.Element("Name")?.Value,
                         Price = d.Element("Price")?.Value,
                         Dates = d.Element("Dates")?.Value,
                         Quantity = d.Element("Quantity").Value,
                         Total = d.Element("Quantity") != null && d.Element("Price") != null ? Convert.ToInt32(d.Element("Quantity").Value) * Convert.ToInt32(d.Element("Price").Value) : 0,
                         Notes = d.Element("Notes")?.Value,
                     };

        XDocument newDoc =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("DATASET",
                result.Select(x => new XElement("DS",
                    new XElement("Name", x.Name),
                    new XElement("Price", x.Price),
                    new XElement("Dates", x.Dates),
                    new XElement("Quantity", x.Quantity),
                    new XElement("Total", x.Total),
                    new XElement("Notes", x.Notes)))));

        newDoc.Save(@"updated.xml");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

You updated XML look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DATASET>
  <DS>
    <Name>AB</Name>
    <Price>17000</Price>
    <Dates>10/12/2018</Dates>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Total>34000</Total>      <= (34000 = 2 * 17000)
    <Notes></Notes>
  </DS>
  <DS>
    <Name>CD</Name>
    <Price>20000</Price>
    <Dates>10/12/2018</Dates>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Total>60000</Total>      <= (60000 = 3 * 20000)
    <Notes></Notes>
  </DS>
</DATASET>
```

Comment: @SamsonWu, if answer was helpful to you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: I tried testing your solution in Winforms and it failed with CS0115 CS0103 CS0117 etc.
Next I tried using doc.Save(path); to overwrite "total's value" to xml file but it didn't work. Is there anyway can I save it back ?

Comment: Currently I am out from my office. You please copy all your error. I'll try to resolve asap. Also I'll try to give you code for write updated data into xml :)

Comment: One suggestion is that you first try my code in console app and make sure to reference all the namespace that required to get rid from compile time CS errors and let me know.

Comment: So try same code on your windows form app and put all code on one button click and let me know.

Comment: @SamsonWu, I added a code to write updated `Total` values to xml. kindly read solution carefully and also see the output :)

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int price = doc.Descendants("DS").Select(x => (int)x.Element("Price") * (int)x.Element("Quantity")).Sum(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path); 
Can I use those lines to replace Xdocument?

Comment: XmlDocument is the older Net Library.  XDocument is a newer Net library that uses Linq.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can be used for this purpose. Check the code below. It is fairly simple though.

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("yourxml.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

Double total = (double)navigator.Evaluate("sum(//DATASET/DS/(Price*Quantity))");
```

**PS: You need XPath 2.0 or higher for this operation. And It works on any platform**